# How to use c++ module with yaws

Tags: c++, cgi, yaws

I don't have experience in using c++ with apache or other web server. But now want to use it with yaws to generate pdf from passed data. May be somebody has experience in doing so. Please any link. I havent found any. May be better to not use executable file but library and call its functions from yaws module.

Answer (score 0):

Since you included the `cgi` tag on your question, one way to do this is to use the [Yaws CGI capabilities](http://yaws.hyber.org/cgi.yaws). You'd simply run your C++ program as a CGI program. Yaws also supports FCGI, which lets you avoid starting a new instance of your C++ program for every request and instead have a dedicated TCP connection between Yaws and a daemon instance of your program.

Another way to do this is to write a [Yaws appmod](http://yaws.hyber.org/appmods.yaws) exporting an `out/1` function. The argument to this will be an `#arg` record detailing all the information of the request being served. Your `out/1` function could then call into an [Erlang NIF](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erl_nif.html) written in C++, passing whatever information from the request it needs, and then taking replies and giving them back to Yaws as responses. PDF data could be returned from your NIF as Erlang binaries.  With this approach, your C++ code runs in the same OS process as Yaws, so you have to be careful that your code never crashes else it will take the whole Erlang VM down with it, but aside from that this approach would be more efficient than FCGI or CGI.